# Can is_page() be combined with a switch control structure?

Tags: php

I'm using an if/else control structure to add class attributes to tags. Could I use a switch control structure instead and if so, how? If not, is there a better way to do this than what I'm doing?

```
<div <?php if (is_page( 'project' )) { echo 'class="project"'; }
        elseif (is_page('home')) {echo 'class="home"'; }
        elseif (is_page('contact')) {echo 'class="contact"'; }
    ?>>
</div>
```

Comment: How should we give you an answer without seeing the code you're already using? It's hard to imagine what you're after without code. Please add it. Thanks.

Comment: This is an abstract concept question. And a simple at that. Do you consider it unwarranted? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Ben's answer is basically correct, is_page also checks to make sure that the query is indeed a Page and not something else with the same post_name.

So to be 100% accurate, you could do something like this:

```
if ( is_page() ) { // only do this for actual pages
  $page_obj = get_queried_object();
  switch ( $page_obj->post_name ) {
    // same switch as Ben's answer
  }
} else { 
  // not a page
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I needed. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, now we have something to work with.

```
switch($post->post_name)
{
    case "project" :
        echo 'class="project"';
        break;
    case "home" :
        echo 'class="home"';
        break;
    case "contact" :
        echo 'class="contact"';
        break;
}
```

A switch is a way for saying "pick one of these choices based on this variables value" but an if/else statement is just a series of boolean checks. So, in your instance, a switch is the clear winner.